# HTML form is submitting successfully even though required fields are empty

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have an HTML file in a Web App in a Google Sheet and I have 2 required fields in the HTML Form but the user can still submit the form without populating those fields with the "Get Location" button even though they are required fields. These fields are Latitude and Longitude.

I tried to remove the placeholder and I tried to remove the style but nothing worked so far.

Here's a link to the Sheet and it's code: [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TwtY9mdBvYqIp-u57Wk059FWwuI0Bbfpg3LeTktSBFw/edit?usp=sharing)

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-16">
    <title>Google Sheet Form</title>
    <style>
      form {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 1rem;
      }

      label {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      input[type="text"],
      input[type="email"] {
        padding: 0.5rem;
        border: 2px solid gray;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        font-size: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
      }

      /* Adjust Get Location button size */
    button[type="button"] {
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 0.5rem;
      font-size: 5rem; /* Change this value to adjust the font size */
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

      button[type="submit"] {
        padding: 0.5rem;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        font-size: 5rem;
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      button[type="submit"]:hover {
        background-color: darkblue;
      }
    </style>

    

    <script>
    function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
      }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      document.getElementById("Latitude").value = latitude;
      document.getElementById("Longitude").value = longitude;
    }

    function showSuccessMessage() {
      const successMessage = document.getElementById('successMessage');
      successMessage.style.display = 'block';
    }

    // I added this function.
    function sample1(e) {
      google.script.run.withFailureHandler(err => console.log(err))
      .withSuccessHandler(f => {
        const responseText = '{"result": "success"}';
        const response = JSON.parse(responseText);
        if (response.result === 'success') {
          showSuccessMessage();
        }
      }).sample2(e);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <form>
    <span>Logged In: <?= email ?></span>
    <p> <input size="20" name="Email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required value="<?= email ?>" readonly> </p>
    <p> <input size="20" type="text" id="Latitude" name="Latitude" required readonly> </p>
    <p> <input size="20" type="text" id="Longitude" name="Longitude" placeholder="Longitude" required readonly> </p>
    <p> <button size="20" type="button" onclick="getLocation()">Get Location</button> </p>
    <p> <button size="20" type="submit" onclick="sample1(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;">Sign In/Sign Out</button>
    </p>

    <!-- Add a div to display the success message -->
    <div id="successMessage" style="display: none;">Form submitted successfully!</div>

    <!-- Add a div to display the error message -->
    <div id="errorMessage" style="display: none;">An error occurred. Please try again.</div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to remove the placeholder and I tried to remove the style but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You don't want to submit the values when Latitude and/or Longitude are not inputted.

In this case, how about checking the values of Latitude and Longitude? Please modify the function `sample1` of Javascript as follows.

#### From:

```
function sample1(e) {
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(err => console.log(err))
  .withSuccessHandler(f => {
    const responseText = '{"result": "success"}';
    const response = JSON.parse(responseText);
    if (response.result === 'success') {
      showSuccessMessage();
    }
  }).sample2(e);
}
```

#### To:

```
function sample1(e) {
  const latitude = document.getElementById("Latitude").value;
  const longitude = document.getElementById("Longitude").value;
  if ([latitude, longitude].includes("")) {
    alert("Latitude and/or Longitude are not inputted.");
  } else {
    google.script.run.withFailureHandler(err => console.log(err))
    .withSuccessHandler(f => {
      const responseText = '{"result": "success"}';
      const response = JSON.parse(responseText);
      if (response.result === 'success') {
        showSuccessMessage();
      }
    }).sample2(e);
  }
}
```

- In this modification, when Latitude and/or Longitude are not inputted, the alert dialog is opened and the submit is not run.
- If you don't want to open the alert dialog, please remove `alert("Latitude and/or Longitude are not inputted.");`.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike you seem like such a kind soul that I feel bad for bugging you with this again, but the code stopped working today. The HTML returns the successMessage without adding a row to the Sheet. I tried to copy the code from this post so that it's exaclty the same as yesterday when it worked perfectly but it still doesn't add a row to the Sheet :(

Comment: @Pieter le Roux I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: @Pieter le Roux When you post your new question, please include more information for correctly replicating your current issue. By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: I will post it as a new question thank you